# Is there any systemd equivalent to "initctl emit"?

Tags: systemd, upstart

In `upstart`, it was possible to send custom events with `initctl emit custom-event`. It was also possible to use these custom events on the `start on` and `stop on` stanzas. Does systemd provides something similar to this? There is no mention of it on the [SystemdForUpstartUsers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) page of Ubuntu wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  This is one of the fundamental differences between `upstart` and `systemd`.  `upstart` is event-based, one of the novel design features that was touted when it was introduced.  `systemd` is not event-based.

You'll have to work out what you are using `initctl emit` *for*, and determine how to achieve that in the different `systemd` model.